# Jetpack compose Box layout clip showing white background

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, boxlayout

Compose Box layout showing white background when applying Clip Option

[image: Box layout Showing white background when clip apply]

```
Box( modifier = Modifier        
    .size(50.dp)
    .clip(CircleShape)
    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.black_trans))
)
```

Is there any way to transparent the background when CircleClip is applied?

Comment: it doesn't looks like while background comes from the box. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) where it's clear how you set the parent with its background.

Answer (score 3):

```
Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(25))
                    .background(Color.Blue)
```

In Modifier order metters so we have to add background at last.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
Box( modifier = Modifier        
    .size(50.dp)
    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.black_trans))
    .clip(CircleShape)
)
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose the order of the modifiers matters. So add background color first and then clip.

```
Box( modifier = Modifier        
.size(50.dp)
.background(colorResource(id = R.color.black_trans))
.clip(CircleShape)
)
```

Modifier Reference:  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#order-modifier-matters